# Convert LineNumber to int

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I'm trying to use the output as variable from this:

```
  $start=Get-Content C:\iampx_v4.6\c.txt | Select-String 'tvg-name="MI:'| Select-Object -First 1 | Select-Object LineNumber
```

So fo example the output is:

```
LineNumber
----------
404
```

Now I want to use it here:

```
$conToDel = Get-Content C:\iampx_v4.6\c.m3u
$conToDel | 
  ForEach-Object { 
    if ($_.ReadCount -ge 1 -and $_.ReadCount -le $start) { 
      $_ -replace '.','' 
    } else { 
      $_ 
    } 
  } |
```

But for this I need to cast first the line number to int and I only can `ToString`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try :

```
$start = Get-Content C:\iampx_v4.6\c.txt | 
   Select-String 'tvg-name="MI:'| 
   Select-Object -First 1 | 
   Select-Object -ExpandProperty LineNumber
```

Comment: `Select-Object -ExpandProperty LineNumber` -> ExpandProperty returns the value of the property. If you only use Select-object LineNumber PS will forward the object to Out-Default, which will convert the object to a string.

Comment: @AndreasMewald I'm aware of this. The op wants to compare -le to an int.

Comment: Still, an explanation of the observed behavior and why your code sample resolves the problem would make this answer more useful to the next person.

Comment: @AndreasMewald Thanks for the detailed explanation, I missed to include at the end of a long night shift.

Answer (score 0):

If `$start` contains the number as a string then you can just cast it to an `int` like this:

```
[int]$start
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way.

```
$start = (Get-Content .\c.txt |
    Select-String 'tvg-name="MI:' |
    Select-Object -First 1).LineNumber
```